# UIActionSheet with mixed style labels?

Tags: ios, ios7, uiactionsheet

Is there a way to have an UIActionSheet with mixed style labels? For example, instead of

Travis Bench (F00008)
Outback (F00056)

I might want it to be shown as

**Travis Bench** (*F00008*)
**Outback** (*F00056*)

I saw some examples, where one cheats and enumerates the subviews of the sheet before it is shown, and doctors it up. I'm OK with that if it has to be that way. In pseudo code, I think it needs to be something like:

```
for (view in sheet.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOf: UIButton]) {
        [view setAttributedTitle: something forState: UIControlStateNormal];}}
```

I fall apart at the `something` there though. I've looked at the `NSAttributedString` reference, and I don't (yet?) see how that's meant to be used to make strings that are partially bold or partially italicized or... anything really.

Is what I want to do even possible?

Comment: Why not search for a custom 3rd party implementation?

Comment: Well, I'm already using the cocoanetics blockified ActionSheet. I did look for answers before I asked, and I didn't see anything out there, 3rd party solution or similar questions.

Comment: Your question really appears to be about `NSAttributedString` since it seems you don't know how to create the attributed string. Look at `NSMutableAttributedString`. Add the bold text then the italic text.